# PHP: Multi Curl using Methods from some Library instead of URLs?

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, instagram

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm just wondering if this is possible or if I'm supposed to do something else...

When using multi-curl one would use URLs right?

```
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

etc..
```

Per the multi-curl [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)...

So what if I have some method (I think thats what you call it) that I'm using from a [library](https://github.com/galen/PHP-Instagram-API)

```
$tags = $instagram->searchTags( 'tag' );
```

Now thats searching the library of the word `tag`. But what if I want to be able to do multiple searches,

```
$tags1 = $instagram->searchTags( 'tag' );
$tags2 = $instagram->searchTags( 'tagme' );
```

How do I implement this into multi curl? Is it just simply replacing the URLs with `$tags1` and `tags2`?

Comment: Can you tell more about why you need cURL multi handler? I think you can create a new handler whenever you need a connection.

Comment: In what way is this relevant to multi cURL?

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe @silkfire because I need to do a request at once, instead of having the request done one at a time. Right now if I request `$tags1` I'll have to wait until thats finished and then it will request `$tags2`

Answer (score 0):

This is without your class, dont see why you need that.

```
function fetchHTML($website) {
  if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
    $ch = curl_init($website);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
  } else {
    $content = file_get_contents($website)
  }
  return $content;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(fetchHTML("http://example1.com"));
$tag1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tagname');

$dom->loadHTML(fetchHTML("http://example2.com"));
$tag2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tagname');

/* Will give you a DOM object list with your first tagname */
print_r($tag1);

/* Will give you a DOM object list with your second tagname */
print_r($tag2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into that PHP library anh found that each instance of the `Instagram` class use only one cURL handler, which leads to the fact that you cannot send multiple request asynchronously.

You can read this article [about connection Sharing with CURL in PHP](http://technosophos.com/content/connection-sharing-curl-php-how-re-use-http-connections-knock-70-rest-network-time) to get the idea of modify the `CurlClient` class of the Instagram library. The main idea here is keep a static class member which hold a handler from `curl_multi_init()` and add each new cURL single handler to it when you need.